# How to end an input when enter is passed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int array[1000]={0}, n, c, d, swap;
    printf("Enter number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

    for (c = 0; c<n; c++)
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);


    for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
        {
            if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
            {
                swap       = array[d];
                array[d]   = array[d+1];
                array[d+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

    for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
        printf("%d\n", array[c]);

    int result= array[n-1]-array[0];
    printf("The difference between the largest and smallest: %d",result);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

This program bubble sorts the inputs first and gives the output of the difference between the largest and smallest number. I want to end the input when I type `enter`. For example, input = `6 4 2` , output= `4`. (end the input by 'enter')

Comment: `How to end an input when enter is passed` end of input is already marked by pressing `ENTER` for almost all the i/p APIs. Please state your problem correctly.

Comment: No, end of input (that is end-of-file on a terminal) is *not* the `ENTER` key (on Linux, it is `Ctrl-D`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27150437/971127

Answer (score 1):

To end input when <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` occurs is challenging using `scanf("%d",...` as `"%d"` first consumes any white-space including `'\n'`.  Need a different way to watch for  `'\n'` first.

```
for (c = 0; c<n; c++)
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && isspace(ch));
  if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) break;
  ungetc(ch, stdin);
  if (scanf("%d", &array[c]) != 1) Handle_NonNumericInput();
}
```

or better yet, use `fgets()`.  Easy to catch all sorts of invalid input.

```
#include <limits.h>
#define MAX_INT_SIZE (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)

c = 0;
char buf[n*(MAX_INT_SIZE + 1) + 2];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  char *p = buf;
  for (; c<n; c++)
    int n;
    if (sscanf(p, "%d %n", &array[c], &n) != 1) break;
    p += n;
  }
  if (*p) Handle_Missing_or_Extra_or_Nonnumeric_input(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a whole line, e.g. with [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), or even (if running on a terminal, e.g.  under Linux) [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) (which offers editing abilities). Then convert each line to a number using [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) or [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) and test when the conversion fails.

Something like

```
 const int arraysize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); // 1000
 printf("Enter at most %d integers ended by a blank line\n", arraysize);
 for (c = 0; c<arraysize; c++) {
    char linebuf[80];
    memset(linebuf, 0, sizeof(linebuf)); // perhaps unneeded
    if (!fgets(linebuf, sizeof(linebuf), stdin))
       break;
    if (sscanf(linebuf, "%d", &array[c])<=0)
       break;
 }
 // here c contains the number of actually read integers.
```

Read the documentation of every function that you are using. Notice that `scanf`, `fscanf` and `sscanf`are returning the count of successfully scanned items.

The clearing [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) is probably unneeded .. but just in case I always clear buffer.

Comment: Minor: `' '` is not needed in `" %d"`. `"%d"` consumes leading white-space even without `' '`

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your problem is you want to break the following for loop after entering the numbers.

```
for (c = 0; c<n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
```

If that's the case. Then you can use following loop.

```
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[c]) != 1 ) {
              n = c; // actual number of integer input.
              break;
        }
    }
```

Now if you enter some alphabet followed by a enter key then it breaks the for loop.